# Динамическое изменение переменной для выбора действий обработчика события

Tags: javascript

Событие мыши должно вызвать одну из двух функций, в зависимости от условия flag=0, либо flag = 1. Как переопределить переменную flag, что бы срабатывала та или другая функция, в зависимости от значения этой переменной. Пробовал уже самыми разными способами. Ничего не выходит.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    flag=0;
    window.onload = function() {
           canvas = document.getElementById("Canva");
          context = canvas.getContext("2d");
           canvas.onmousedown = show;

    if(flag == 0)
        { canvas.onmousdown = show;}
        else if(flag == 1)
        {canvas.onmousdown = show2;}
          }

      function show() 
    { 
     alert('Next');
    } 
    function show2() 
    { 
     alert('Stop');
    } 
</script>
```

Можно ставить if else и в условии вызова алертов в самой функции. Но суть не меняется, переменную флаг переопределить никак не выходит.

Answer (score 1):

1. При первом упоминании (объявлении) переменной используй `var`.
2. Ты не правильно задал обработчик событий клика для canvas, смотри пример, как правильно:

```js
var flag = 0;

window.onload = function() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("Canva");
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
      if(flag == 0) {
        flag = 1;

        show();
      } else {
        flag = 0;

        show2();
      }
    }, false);
}
 
function show() {
    alert('Next');
}

function show2() {
   alert('Stop');
}
```

```css
#Canva {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="Canva"></canvas>
```

Comment: Если заменить на onmousedown - не работает. Мне вообще onmousemove обрабатывать надо. Я в этом примере всё значительно упростил для читабельности.

Comment: В addEventListener нужно использовать без on. Если нужно onmousemove -- пропишите `mousemove`.

Comment: Если прописать mousemove вместо onmosemove код перестаёт работать.

Comment: залейте свой код на http://pastebin.com и предоставьте ссылку